# How to run jest tests in SPFx when importing @microsoft/sp-core-library?

Tags: jestjs, enzyme, spfx, ts-jest

The below error occurs when running npm test in a SharePoint Framework web part with a react component that imports **DisplayMode** from **'@microsoft/sp-core-library'**:

```
export { default as _BrowserDetection } from './BrowserDetection';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

Following the resolution steps mentioned in https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2325#issuecomment-446416878 works fine for testing but fails for the build process.